# Why a new row is not added when the value is not exist?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table for counting the views:

```
             post_views table
    ___________________________________
   |        |             |           |
   |   id   |   post_id   |   views   |
   |________|_____________|___________|
```

Where the `post_id` is related to the `id` of `posts` table:

```
               posts table
    __________________________________________
   |        |           |          |         |
   |   id   |   title   |   text   |    ..   |
   |________|___________|__________|_________|
```

Each `id` from `posts` should has one row in the `post_views` table, So the `id` is primary in views table and `post_id` is unique.

I want to increase the `views` count if the `post_id` exists, Else insert that new `post_id`.

So I'm using that query:

```
INSERT INTO post_views (`post_id`, `views`) VALUES (1, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `views` = `views`+1
```

That created a new row with `id` = 0:

```
____________________________________
|          |             |           |
|    id    |   post_id   |   views   |
|__________|_____________|___________|
|          |             |           |
|    0     |     1       |    1      |
|          |             |           |
|__________|_____________|___________|
```

And whenever I run the same query with a new `post_id`:

```
INSERT INTO post_views (`post_id`, `views`) VALUES (2, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `views` = `views`+1
```

The views in the same existing row increases and the new `post_id` is not added:

```
 ____________________________________
|          |             |           |
|    id    |   post_id   |   views   |
|__________|_____________|___________|
|          |             |           |
|    0     |     1       |    2      |
|          |             |           |
|__________|_____________|___________|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not declared the `id` to be `auto_increment`.  Your table declaration should look like:

```
create table post_views (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    post_id int not null,
    . . . 
);
```

When you leave the `id` out of the insert, it is getting a default value.  With `auto_increment` the default is an incrementing `id`.

You have probably specified that `id` is `not null` (or `primary key`) with a default of `0`.  This is true for all inserts, so all attempted inserts have the same value.  The `auto_increment` should fix this problem.

Comment: Yes you are right, I forgot to set the id to auto_increment

Comment: But there is another thing, When I run the same query twice a new row is added and the views is increased to 2, But then when I enter a new `post_id` the id becomes 3, then 5 ..

Comment: So each time I run the same query `INSERT INTO post_views (`post_id`, `views`) VALUES (1, 0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `views` = `views`+1`, That's considered as a new id

Comment: Then when I try `INSERT INTO post_views (`post_id`, `views`) VALUES (2, 0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `views` = `views`+1`, the row id becomes 3

Comment: @Dan . . . I think you need a unique index on `post_id`.

Comment: The id is primary and auto_increment and the post_id is unique

Comment: When I run the query, I get a success message saying that 2 rows affected